# Setting Range.Value causes #VALUE! in Excel VBA, and also resubmitting a function causes all other functions to be resubmitted

Tags: excel, vba

I apologise for how trivial this must be for VBA developers, but I have done some digging and cannot fathom why the following code, when assigned to a cell and executed, results in #VALUE!

```
Function foo()
    Range("A1:B3").Value = 10
End Function
```

The excel sheet:

[image: excel]

I initially tried

```
ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value = "abc"
```

but that didn't work either.  What very simple thing am I doing wrong here?

Also, why, when I try to re-execute the function (using F2 and then Enter), does excel resubmit other functions that are in the same worksheet?  This is truly maddening. I have hit F2 and Enter, so why would Excel think that I want to resubmit all other functions, and how can this be prevented?
Thanks very much.

Comment: `foo` is a UDF (user-defined function). UDFs take parameters and return a value *to the cell that invoked it*. They don't (can't) alter any other cell's value, or alter any application state. This `#VALUE!` error means "You're trying to make a UDF do something it's not allowed to do".

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/170787/description-of-limitations-of-custom-functions-in-excel

Comment: I see.  So how is this supposed to be done?  OK I can create it as a procedure (using Sub .. End Sub) instead of a function but how then is that supposed to be invoked? I have tried to create it as a sub and then call the sub from the function but that doesn't work either (unsurprisingly).  None of the examples that I've seen on the web say how this is supposed to be done. They just say eg Range("A1").Value=10 and it's supposed to just "work" but clearly it's not as simple as that.  Surely I don't have to create a new macro every time I want to do something like this?

Comment: Public parameterless `Sub` procedures can be attached to any shape or "forms" control, or invoked from any worksheet or workbook or ActiveX control event handler. Depends what you're *actually* trying to achieve.

Comment: Make `foo` a `Sub` procedure, then draw some rectangle shape; right-click it, select "attach macro", select "foo", done.

Comment: Oh you mean add a button, assign the procedure.  I see.  Yes that works, thank you. I was really looking for a way to update other cells' values based on executing a function, but I see now that that is not possible. I will continue to look into other ways to do it; eg using some kind of event notification (I am presuming that VBA has such a thing).  Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: You tried to use UDF for changing some fields and consistent about the use of some kind of event modification instead of firing your code from a button in your comments with @Mathieu Guindon. Since UDF fire the code only when some cells are recalculated, it is assumed that your requirement is to fire the code when some cells in the sheet get changed either manually or through some formula. The solutions offered below run the code when value of cell F1 change. You may please modify it according to your need.

Old Post: It is not a clean way but may be a called dirty workaround idea. Supposing you want to  any change in cell F1 value to execute the code, may try

```
Public F1Val As Variant
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
F1Val = Range("F1").Value
End Sub
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If F1Val <> Range("F1").Value Then
Range("A1:B3").Value = 10
F1Val = Range("F1").Value
End If
End Sub
```

**Caution**:Certainly it will backfire if cell F1 is linked with formula with the cells getting changed.

Alternately if *only manual change* of cell F1 is suffice for code to execute then may simply try

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("F1")) Is Nothing Then
Range("A1:B3").Value = 10
End If
End Sub
```